# Audio is playing in Avplayer after close AvPlayerViewController ios

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

Hi in my application I have avplayerViewController. I just launch the application and click on start play button - which will launch avplayerviewcontroller. There i just drag the seek bar and content is buffering before content start play i just close the playerViewcontroller. After few seconds content is start playing (audio is coming). It's very serious issue please guide me how to resolve this issue. As of now when ever i close the player i am doing below operations.

```
@try{

        [self.player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:nil];
        [self.player setRate:0.0];
        [self.player seekToTime:CMTimeMake(0, 1)];
        [self.player pause];


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.contentOverlayView sendSubviewToBack:self->playerActivityIndicator];
            [self->playerActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
        });
        // [[self.player currentItem] removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"];
        [[self.player currentItem] removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferEmpty"];

        [self.player removeTimeObserver:self->playerPeriodicTimeObserver];


    }@catch(id anException){
        //do nothing, obviously it wasn't attached because an exception was thrown
        NSLog(@"No observer for a player in hide placeholder");
    }
```

Comment: Seems it is not deallocating. Add `dealloc` to the`avplayerViewController ` and check if it is called.

Comment: Even like said it's not reallocated how can we handle after dismiss this playerviewcontroller.

Comment: If i launch default AvplayerViewCOntroller directly without subclassing that time how can i know wether dealloc is called or not.

Comment: Hi Satish -(void)dealloc method is not calling in my AvPlayerVIewcontroller subclass. Even i removed all observers but still few observers are calling after dismiss playerviewcontroller. What can be the reason pls let me know.

Comment: `playerviewcontroller` is not getting released, something is holding `playerviewcontroller` instance even after dismiss. Might be able to help if the full code that present/dismiss `playerviewcontroller` is shared.

Comment: yes i can share pls tell me the email id

Comment: It's very urgent to me.